# How can I remove a location which is not a place from my Google Timeline?

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to make my location history more accurate.

In the old Location History I had a chance to click on specific coordinates and remove them. (I find it that my phone reports inaccurate locations to Google's servers quite often, especially when I use the subway or when there are Wi-Fi hotspots nearby which don't have a fixed position.)

Is there a way to still remove specific coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your [Location Timeline](https://www.google.com/maps/timeline)
2. Navigate to the date you want to change
3. Find the stop you want to remove; click the action menu (three vertical dots)
4. Choose "Remove stop from day"

The map will still show you were in the area, but it won't call out that stop specifically.